# Spring disable transactions for a single class method

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-transactions

In my Spring application, I have a class annotated with `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` annotation.

Is it possible to discard transactions for a specific single method of this class without removing `@Transactional` from class level declarations? If so, please show an example

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) documentation:

```
public @interface Transactional

Describes a transaction attribute on an individual method or on a class.
```

So additionally to the class-level annotation just define the correct attribute at your method to disable the default transaction handling.

example:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER)
public long notInTransaction(AnythingData anythingData) throws Exception {
   //JDBC code...
}
```

Will throw an exception if this method is called inside an active transaction. Whereas `Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED` will "suspend" the current transaction and make sure that the method is called non transactional.

Comment: With my configuration (Spring 4.3.10, EclipseLink 2.7.6) this did not work. I.e. a transaction is started despite having `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER)` on method level. As soon, as I remove the `@Transactional` from class level, no transaction is created. FYI, it should not matter, but I am using a named transaction manager and specific rollback conditions.

Comment: Looks like a Bug in your Transactionmanagmentframework.